# Mature WebSocket / Socket.io server side implementations?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, comet

I have closed-source server-side software that communicates with proprietary messages over TCP.

I would like to program a client for this server that runs in the Safari web browser (an iPad).

I believe the best way to do this is to create a middleware program that translates between the WebSocket or Socket.io protocol and the proprietary format used by the server.

I'd be most comfortable writing the midleware in C/C++ or Java, but other languages readily usable on linux would also work.  The connection to the server can not be closed between calls and we need to maintain state, so languages like php are probably not appropriate.

I've looked at a half-dozen server side Socket.io implementations, but nothing stood out as being ready for prime-time.

What are some mature sever-side platforms / libraries for a browser socket implementation out there?  The things that are most important to me are:

1. Stability... It should run for months without being restarted
2. Maintenance and Community... No dead projects

While it seems like nothing is truly mature in this area, any hints as to the best possible paths for a production system would be appreciated.

Comment: There also seems to be some phonegap extensions that would let me skip the middleware step altogether.  Can anyone recommend a particular extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to grasp what you really want to know from us.

> I've looked at a half-dozen server side Socket.io implementations, but
>   nothing stood out as being ready for prime-time.

I believe http://socket.io/ for node.js is pretty stable, used by many, has a huge community, and is by far not dead.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I'm looking for a server-side component.  Of which socket.io has many different implementations.  I'd like to know if anyone can recommend a particular implementation.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Isn't there exactly *one* Node.JS Socket.IO server?

Comment: Thanks. socket.io doesn't have a clear download link, so it looked to me more like a specification with lots of implementations than an actual implementation in and of itself.  After visiting the git-hub page however things got better :-)